# Rearrange style order in ccs bundle

Tags: css, webpack, gruntjs, less

After a migration from grunt, the styles are not working as intended with webpack. All the styles were concatenated in the `gruntfile` like this:

```
target: {
    files: {
        "all.css": [
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "bower_components/toastr/toastr.css",
            "bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css",
            "node_modules/font-awesome/font-awesome.css",
            "bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css",
            "bower_components/angular-ui-tree/dist/angular-ui-tree.css",
            "content/styles/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css",
            "content/styles/tradesolution.css",
            "content/styles/site.css",
            "content/styles/ts.css",
            "content/styles/nyKladd.css"
        ]
    }
}
```

My current config in webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var globby = require('globby');
var path = require('path');

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');

const ConcatPlugin = require('webpack-concat-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: globby.sync(['./app/app.js','./app/app.run.js', './app/app.config.js', './app/**/*.js']),
        Ztyles: globby.sync(['./content/styles/less/*.less']), 
        styles: globby.sync(['./content/styles/*.css']),
        images: globby.sync(['./content/images/**/*.*']),
        vendor: [
               // removed to save space
        ],
    },
    output: {
        
        filename: './scripts/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, "public")
        
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 1384,
        contentBase: './public/'
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: (() => {
        if(NODE_ENV = "devlopment") return 'source-map'
        else return 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
    }) (),

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: extractCSS.extract(
                    { fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' }
                ),
                //'style-loader', 'css-loader'
            },
            {    test: /\.less$/,
                 use: extractLESS.extract(
                     {fallback:'style-loader', use: ['css-loader','less-loader']}
                )
                //'style-loader', 'css-loader!less-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?name=./[name].[ext]",
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "content", "images")
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|tiff|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=/[path]/[name].[ext]',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "content", "images"),
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=./fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]' },
            {
                test: require.resolve('adal-angular/lib/adal'),
                loader: 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                loader: 'source-map-loader'
            }
        ],
    },
    
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ADMIN_API_URL: JSON.stringify('http://localhost:41118/api/'),
            API_URL: JSON.stringify('http://epdapi.tradesolution.no/'),
            GLOBAL_ADMIN_URL: JSON.stringify('https://adminapi.tradesolution.no/')
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './app/layout.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        extractCSS,
        extractLESS,
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: './scripts/vendor.bundle.js' }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: './[name].bundle.css' }),
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: 'webpack.assets.json',
            path: './public',
            prettyPrint: true
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            "window.AuthenticationContext": "AuthenticationContext",
            _: 'underscore'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: './app/**/*.html', to: './'}
        ]),
        new DashboardPlugin()
    ],
    externals: [
        { xmlhttprequest: '{XMLHttpRequest:XMLHttpRequest}' }
    ], 
    
}
```

[image: elements tab devtools]
From this picture you can see that the default bootstrap styles are overriding the styles written for the nav-bar.

What i have done so far is to implement all the other css files into one less file, like this:

```
@import "../tradesolution.css";
@import "../site.css";
@import "../nykladd.css";
@import "for";
@import "kladd.less";
@import "~bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "~bootstrap/less/alerts.less";
@import "~bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less";
@import "~font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
```

Then the less file is compiled to css and loaded in the `Ztyles.css` , but regardless of where I put the imports, my styles are still overridden. I have also tried changing the order of the webpack rules and the order of `extractCSS` and `extractLESS` in plugins

I dont think my intended solution is good practice, so any approach to solving this issue is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i stumbled over a new css framework `postcss` they have all kinds of plugins, and with this configuration I got it to work:

```
{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 
                    'style-loader',
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true, importLoaders: 1 }, 
                     loader: 'postcss-loader', 
                    },
                ]
            },
            {    test: /\.less$/,
                use: extractLESS.extract(
                    {fallback:'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader']}
                )
            },
```

Here are some resources that helped:

https://github.com/postcss/postcss

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-postcss-together-with-sass-stylus-or-less--cms-24591

https://github.com/Crunch/postcss-less